# Configure aws workmail to send email with c#

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-workmail

I am trying to configure the gate away of EC2 WorkMail

Sorry for my novice question , I do not know what to put in Gateway address and gateway name. Do it need to create it ?

For port number I have put **587** [image]

Comment: I think that means 'route all my outbound email through an external gateway' not 'set up a gateway that I can send email to'. Do you need the email to be sent from the mailbox itself? If so you can probably attach to the mailbox using an Exchange client library, or Exchange Web Services (I assume WorkMail provides that?). If not, your WorkMail will be set up with Amazon SES so you can just use SES directly.

Comment: My mistake: there is already an outbound gateway you can use. https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2017/05/amazon-workmail-now-offers-an-smtp-gateway-for-sending-email/ You want the 'SMTP via TLS (port 465)' entry in [this table](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/rande.html#wm_region).

Comment: I would like to not use SES

Comment: if you don't want to use SES, how are you planning to relay your emails ? Do you use any other email reply service e.g: google/microsoft/sendmail etc or do you have some email server to yourself ? Those are the gateway and port you need to enter there.

Comment: I have tried to enter port and gateway but it is not working

Comment: When you say 'enter the port and gateway' you mean connect to the host on the page I linked on port 465, not trying to put those details into this form? I did see a post somewhere that says the C# SMTP client defaults to making clear connections then upgrading to TLS whereas Amazon wants you to initiate the connection as TLS, in case that's the mistake you're making. If not can you be more specific about what you're doing and exactly how it's not working - what error messages you're getting back (connection closed, something from the SMTP server, something else)?